# Marathi font not rendered correctly?

Tags: android, fonts

I am creating an android mobile app, which takes data from user and saves to database. Now while generating report I am creating an pdf dynamically using iText pdf creator of version iTextg 5.5.10. I want to show text like this "मासिक दैनंदिनी"but it shows like this "मासकि दैनंदनिी". Also joined words looks like this "कोलहापुर" which should be "कोल्हापुर. We are using "NotoSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf" fontfor marathi font.

We have tried couple of things listed below,
1. We tried pdf box pdf creator but having same issue.
2. Tried different fonts like mangal.ttf, krutidev.ttf.
3. tried unicode fonts using jar files.

I am creating custom font object like this,

```
BaseFont bf_mar = BaseFont.createFont("assets/NotoSansDevanagari- 
Regular.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,true);
Font marathi = new Font(bf_mar , 20,Font.NORMAL);
```

And applying the font to paragraph like this,

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("मासिक दैनंदिनी",marathi);
paragraph.setSpacingAfter(5);
paragraph.setSpacingBefore(5);
document.add(paragraph);
```

I expect the text should appear like this "मासिक दैनंदिनी". Also joined words looks like this "कोलहापुर" which should be "कोल्हापुर

Answer (score 0):

Try without the use of fonts if it is not compulsory to use the exact font in the report.

Comment: I have tried this, if i remove the font  its shows blank.